# xdman zoomed to 500% and is unusable

Tags: interface

I recently installed [Xtreme Download Manager](https://xtremedownloadmanager.com/) on Ubuntu and since the window and all the buttons and texts were too small, I changed the zoom percentage to 500% (!) in options.
Now when I open it, all I can see is a black window with nothing on it. I can't access options (or anything else on the app) anymore so I can't change the zoom options back to normal. As a result, the app is completely unusable.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app put that didn't change anything.
I also lowered the display scale down to 100% but I still can't see any text or buttons on the window.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned anything about your system specs, I assume your are using ubuntu.

Did you uninstall the pkg using the command `sudo apt remove --purge pkgname`? if not then probably the config files from previous install are still existing there and getting used on reinstall. Remove the pkg using the above command and then reinstall it to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu.
I can't uninstall it using this command. (Unable to locate package xdman)

I installed it by executing a file named "install.sh" which I downloaded from xdman website and I uninstalled it using `sudo /opt/xdman/uninstall.sh` as the readme file instructed.

Comment: The above command works for apt packages. I feel the config files are not getting removed when you uninstall the package. Try removing all the folders named xdman or simply the files inside these folders after removing the package and then reinstall it.

Comment: You're right! It's fixed now!
I found a file called .xdman in /home/username and deleted it.
Thanks!

Comment: Actually removing the hidden settings folder would have been enough. Uninstalling/reinstalling stuff is an unfortunate result of a certain "Windows mentality".

Comment: @ChanganAuto : fully agree. missed this point.